# Send a message and process it in multiple Handlers

Tags: android, handler, message

Good afternoon from Mexico,

I have a FragmentActivity which has a Handler, inside i put a Fragment which has is own Handler.

In other side I have a Service that connects to a Socket and sends Messages via mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_SOMETHING).sendToTarget(); as Bluetooth example implements intercomunication between services and activities.

My question is, ¿How can I make my FragmentActivity and Fragment process the same Message that my service sends? I've thinking in a Handler Array or something but I think is a better way to do it.

Sorry for my bad English and have a nice day...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it simple,

First implement a list for Handlers

```
LinkedList<Handler> mHandlers = new LinkedList<Handler>();
LinkedList<String> mTags = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Then I make two functions for register and remove Handler from list

```
private void registerHandler(Handler h, String tag){
    mHandlers.add(h);
    mTags.add(h);
}

private void removeHandler(String tag){
    int index=10000;
    for(int i = 0; i < mTags.size(); i++){
        if(s.equals(mTags.get(i))){
            index=i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(index != 10000){
        mTags.remove(index);
        mHandlers.remove(index);
    }
}
```

And for send messages to n-Handlers i change my function to

```
for(Handler h:mHandlers){
    h.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_SOMETHING).sendToTarget();
}
```

And that's all...